# DJ Hero statistics

Tags: dj-hero

Does DJ Hero provide statistics regarding the progress of the collectible goals?

In other words, is there a way to figure out how many hot starts you have had thus far or how many scratches are still to be completed on the way to the Super Scratchin' achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

The values are tracked by the system but not accessed for display anywhere.

10000 is a lot of scratches, keep going :)